# AWS DocumentDB through Proxy

Tags: ssh-tunnel, mongodb-shell, aws-documentdb

I have an [AWS DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/) set up that I can connect to just fine through my jump box using:

```
mongo --ssl --host aws-host:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username my_user --password <insertYourPassword>
```

I'd like to be able to connect to it through localhost for some testing.  I cannot connect directly so I attempted to open a tunnel from my jump:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-key user@my_jump -L 27017:aws-host:27017 -N
```

After that I tried the basic MongoDB connect command:

```
mongo --ssl --host localhost:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username my_user --password <insertYourPassword>
```

I get an error I understand:

> The server certificate does not match the host name. Hostname: localhost does not match SAN(s)

I tried using `export http_proxy` to use `http://my_jump:27017` and using the command above again with no luck.

Any suggestions or help on how to connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to [disable ssl hostname validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#cmdoption--sslAllowInvalidHostnames):

```
mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidHostnames ...
```

Note **--sslAllowInvalidHostnames** is available from ***version 3.0***.

If this does not work, try to remove `--ssl` entirely from the connection options, as according to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-host):

> The mongo shell verifies that the hostname (specified in --host option
>   or the connection string) matches the SAN (or, if SAN is not present,
>   the CN) in the certificate presented by the mongod or mongos. If SAN
>   is present, mongo does not match against the CN. If the hostname does
>   not match the SAN (or CN), the mongo shell will fail to connect.

Comment: Yes!  The key here is **version 3.0** as well.  I had to upgrade the client to actually get it to work.

Comment: I can connect on jump_server but cannot connect from my machine ? How to connect from outsie ?

Comment: Please be aware that the official documentation  warns to avoid this flag: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#avoid-use-of-tlsallowinvalidcertificates-option

Comment: Is there any way I can connect to the documentdb behind proxy server without `sslAllowInvalidHostnames`? Even the aws document tells me to use it!